# Operators new and delete in c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I need some help with operators `new` and `delete`

I tried to create a class named big to handle huge numbers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class big
{
protected:
    char *a;
    long lenght,maxlenght;
public:
    big()
    {
        maxlenght=256;
        a=new char[maxlenght];
        memset(a,'\0',maxlenght);
    }
    void read();

    void set_maxlenght(long x);

    long msize();

    long size();

    char* return_big();

    long at(long poz);

    char* operator[](long poz);

    void operator=(big x);

    void modify (long poz,long val);

    void dec (long poz);

    void inc (long poz);

    void operator-(big x);

    int compare(big x);
};




//functions

void write(big x)
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr=x.return_big();
    cout<<ptr;
}


//class big

    void big::read()
    {
        char *buffer;
        buffer=new char[maxlenght];
        memset(buffer,'\0',maxlenght);
        cin>>buffer;
        delete[] a;
        a=new char[strlen(buffer)];
        memset(a,'\0',maxlenght);
        for(long i=0;i<(long)strlen(buffer);i++)
            a[i]=buffer[i];
        lenght=strlen(buffer);
        delete[] buffer;
    }

    void big::set_maxlenght(long x)
    {
        maxlenght=x;
    }

    long big::msize()
    {
        return maxlenght;
    }

    long big::size()
    {
        return lenght;
    }

    char* big::return_big()
    {
        char *x;
        x=a;
        return x;
    }

    long big::at(long poz)
    {
        if(poz>=lenght)
            return -1;
        else
            return this->a[poz];
    }

    char* big::operator[](long poz)
    {
        if(poz>=lenght)
            return NULL;
        else
            return a+poz;
    }

    void big::operator=(big x)
    {
        a=new char[x.size()];
        for(long i=0;i<(long)strlen(x.a);i++)
            this->modify(i,x.at(i));
        this->lenght=strlen(x.a);
    }

    void big::modify (long poz,long val)
    {
        a[poz]=(char)val;
    }

    void big::dec (long poz)
    {
        if(a[poz])
            a[poz]--;
    }

    void big::inc (long poz)
    {
        if(a[poz]<255)
            a[poz]++;
    }

    void big::operator-(big z)
    {
        long n,m,i,j,aux;
        big rez,x,y;
        if(compare(z))
        {
            x=*this;
            y=z;
        }
        else
        {
            y=*this;
            x=z;
        }
        n=x.size();
        m=y.size();
        i=n;
        j=m;
        while(j>=0)
        {
            if(x.at(i)<0)
            {
                x.modify(i-1,x.at(i-1)+x.at(i));
                x.modify(i,0);
            }
            aux=x.at(i)-y.at(j);
            if(aux<0)
            {
                x.dec(i-1);
                rez.modify(i,aux+10);
            }
            else
                rez.modify(i,aux);
        }
        while(i)
        {
            i--;
            if(x.at(i)<0)
            {
                x.modify(i-1,x.at(i-1)+x.at(i));
                x.modify(i,0);
            }
            rez.modify(i,x.at(i));
        }
    }

    int big::compare(big x)
    {
        return strcmp(this->a,x.return_big());
    }

    int main()
    {
        big a,b;
        a.read();
        b.read();
        write(a);
        endl(cout);
        write(b);
        return 0;
    }
```

The first read is ok but the second has this error when it want to execute `a=new char[strlen(buffer)]`:

```
---Windows has triggered an error in MyProject.exe

This may be due to the corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in MyProject.exe or any DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while MyProject.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.---
```

There are also two buttons Break and Continue.
If I press continue it shows me this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77b8380e in Olimpiada a IX-a.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.
```

I'm not very experienced with pointers (6 months). I would appreciate any answers.

Comment: You need to add 1 to the length to accommodate the trailing `NUL` character.  Alternatively use `strdup()` or `std::string` objects.

Comment: *Note: when you want to work with large numbers try library such as `NTL` http://www.shoup.net/ntl/ *

Comment: You shouldn't be using pointers in this code. You should be using `std::vector`. I feel like I should recommend you [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fault occurs here:

```
delete[] a;
a=new char[strlen(buffer)];
memset(a,'\0',maxlenght);
```

i.e. you've just resized your a pointer to, potentially, a smaller size, but, your maxlength variable still has the original size and can overwrite memory here. The patch would be:

```
delete[] a;
maxlength = strlen(buffer);
a=new char[maxlenght];
memset(a,'\0',maxlenght);
```

Also, I've used your mispelt maxlenght variable name. It should be maxlength.

Comment: Yes it was my fault that I haven't changed maxlenght   Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing C++ and not C, you might instead want to use the [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) object instead of `char *`. They are a lot easier to use.

But that said, this line looked a bit off to me:

```
memset(buffer,'\0',maxlenght);
```

In the event that you don't put anything into `buffer`, the result of `strlen(buffer)` will be zero. As a result, your `new` statement will try to allocate space for zero `char` elements. Perhaps that's happening here?

Comment: In this case, a `vector` is probably more appropriate than a `string` since the `char*`s are not really text.

Comment: I was trying to create a class for my C++ experience and I don't know how to use strings very well I will try to use them    thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

The length passed to the second memset isn't right, it should be:

```
memset(a,'\0',strlen(buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong array size on second line:

```
a=new char[strlen(buffer)];
memset(a,'\0',maxlenght);
```

And destructor is missed that causes memory leaks.
Calls of `strlen(buffer)` are very expensive and should be cached.
`std::string` looks better then `char*`.